# Making one set of code (with slight differences) apply to specific textboxes in userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm where I have multiple rows of textboxes for data entry. Upon finishing entry for a specific textbox in each row, it triggers a macro for another textbox within the same row to be calculated.

The code is:

```
Private Sub TextBox46_Change()

    If DataInput.TextBox46.Value > 0 And DataInput.TextBox46.Value < 1000 Then
       DataInput.TextBox54.Value = 100 * ((DataInput.TextBox46.Value - DataInput.TextBox14.Value) / (DataInput.TextBox30.Value - DataInput.TextBox14.Value))
       DataInput.TextBox62.Value = 100 - DataInput.TextBox54.Value
    Else: MsgBox ("Revise Inputs")
    End If
    End Sub
```

Now I need to apply this for 8 other textboxes, except for example if it was TextBox47_Change then all the other textbox numbers in the code must shift up by 1. I have searched online and people have done it but the code did not change. Here,my code has slight differences for each textbox.

Is there a way to repeat this code without just copy and pasting it to each TextBox_Change sub and then changing the numbers.

For further clarification, in the image I have attached, everytime the Dish + Residue Mass column textbox changes then the TSR,VS,FS is calculated for the corresponding row.

Comment: I think I know your problem, perhaps is [like mine a while ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986941/select-variable-object-with-counter)

Comment: It's similar (yours will help on something else that I have planned) except I need this calculation to execute only after each specific textbox has been clicked rather than it all happening all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that will return a reference to the textboxes based on a number.

```
Private Sub TextBox46_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 0
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox47_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox48_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 2
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox49_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 3
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox50_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 4
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox51_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 5
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox52_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 6
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox53_Change()
    TextBox_ChangeEvent 7
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_ChangeEvent(Index As Integer)
    If getTxtBox(46 + Index).Value > 0 And getTxtBox(46 + Index).Value < 1000 Then
        getTxtBox(54 + Index).Value = 100 * ((getTxtBox(46 + Index).Value - getTxtBox(14 + Index).Value) / (getTxtBox(30 + Index).Value - getTxtBox(14 + Index).Value))
        getTxtBox(62 + Index).Value = 100 - getTxtBox(54 + Index).Value
    Else: MsgBox ("Revise Inputs")
    End If
End Sub

Function getTxtBox(Index As Integer) As MSForms.TextBox
    Set getTxtBox = DataInput.Controls("TextBox" & Index)
End Function
```

Comment: But this code will only execute when textbox46 changes? I want it to also run when textbox47, 48 etc. changes as well

Comment: @neeenway I updated my answer.  Alternately you could create a class to group the textbox change events but it's a bit more involved Here is an example of grouping events: [Returning an index value from a group of ActiveX Option Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896458/returning-an-index-value-from-a-group-of-activex-option-buttons/39905641#39905641)

Comment: Thanks so much. It works well. Would learning grouping events be beneficial and will it take long?

Comment: Learning to write your own classes, working with events and grouping events will definitely help.  The more techniques that you learn the faster and more creative you become at programming.  Thanks for accepting my answer :)